# Why does specifying the URL as '0.0.0.0' allow my NestJS-fastify app to deploy to Heroku?

Tags: heroku, nestjs, fastify, nestjs-fastify

When I was trying to deploy my NestJS app to Heroku I was seeing the error `Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch`

**Why does setting the url to `0.0.0.0` make it work?**

```
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
await app.listen(port, '0.0.0.0');
```

Context:

- When I deploy without `0.0.0.0` my app says `Listening at http://127.0.0.1:<randomNumber>`
- When I deploy with `0.0.0.0` my app says `Listening at http://127.0.0.1:<randomNumber>`
- Node version: 16.13.0
- NestJS
- Middleware: Fastify
- Set `NPM_CONFIG_PROD=false`
- No cors
- No helmet

```
"@nestjs/common": "^8.0.0",
"@nestjs/core": "^8.0.0",
"@nestjs/platform-fastify": "^8.0.11",
```

Comment: in your code, are you using `PORT` or `process.env.PORT`?

Comment: I'm using `process.env.PORT`. I've updated the snippet above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`127.0.0.1` - also commonly known as `localhost` - is used as a [Loopback mechanism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localhost#Loopback) which allows the service to listen on the local machine (i.e. your laptop / development server) without needing the internet or even a network interface.

Since this `127.0.0.1` interface is local and internal to the dyno only, Heroku can't connect to it from the network routers that are used to send  requests to your dyno; it expects an external, internet-facing network interface. This is where `0.0.0.0` comes into play. It means that the service should listen for requests on *all* network interfaces, which includes the one(s) that Heroku expects to send requests over. This means that Heroku can use one of those external-facing network interfaces to actually connect & route to your service.

For more information, [check out this thread](https://serverfault.com/questions/78048/whats-the-difference-between-ip-address-0-0-0-0-and-127-0-0-1).